# Where does JSFiddle store my variables?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, jsfiddle

**Introductory comments:** As an experiment, I'm debugging some code with JSFiddle. I have no trouble adding `debugger;` statements or displaying stuff in `alert();` windows. My problem is with the Chrome Console: I'd like to use it to print out the values of variables.

**Illustrative example:** On JSFiddle, I put the following code in the JavaScript box.

```
var sampleVar = "test value";
```

After the code has run, it seems that I have no way of viewing the variable values. I can view them before the program's run to completion, by adding a `debugger;` statement and evaluating `sampleVar` on the console. (As shown by [this (ridiculously simple) JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geKLp/) and [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8cRz.png).)

**Further extrapolation:** But I'd like to be able to open up the complete program and probe through it's variables. Is there a way for me to do that? I tried opening up the console and evaluating `sampleVar` but it appears to be undefined on the top-level scope. (As shown in [this screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03qfa.png))

**Restatement of question** Where is JSFiddle putting my variables? How do I access them?

---

**Postscript:** Sorry for linking to imgur, I thought adding the pictures directly would distract from the question.

**Notable comparison:** Contrast this difficulty debugging JSFiddle with the ease of debugging JSBin. If I open a "Console" frame in JSBin I can recall the variables I declared in my code, no problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where is JSFiddle putting my variables? How do I access them?

It's putting it where you're telling it to. JSFiddle defaults to put all your code in a `window.onload` function which means everything you declare with `var` is local to that callback. (You can of course set properties on `window` explicitly). Here is [such an example](http://jsfiddle.net/y3t8b/).

This setting is changeable from the left hand menu - if you move it to `head` or `body` you will have access to them from the developer tools. Moreover, it's worth mentioning that if you invoke the debugger while that code is running you will have access to those variables even if they are in a closure.

Comment: In what scope does the Google Chrome Console operate? In your JSFiddle, I can't access sampleVar from the console.

Comment: You can access it if you change the frame in your developer tools, their code is run in an iframe. Go to Console -> click on <top frame> and change to result. The frames dropdown is about below 'Network' when you have 'Console' open.

Answer (score 0):

The code is evaluated in an iframe on a different domain (fiddle.jsshell.net). This is done for security reasons.

edit: In Firebug, you can use `cd(document.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow);`, in Chrome you can use the dropdown next to the filter icon to switch frames.